# child number changes when web scraping for different patents

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping

I am relatively new to web scraping.

I am having problems with child numbers when web scraping for multiple patents. The child number changes accordingly to the the location of the table in the web page. Sometimes the child is "div:nth-child(17)" and other times it is "div:nth-child(18)" when searching for different patents.

My line of code is this one:

```
IPCs <-sapply("http://www.sumobrain.com/patents/us/Sonic-pulse-echo-method-apparatus/4202215.html", function(url1){
tryCatch(url1 %>%
  as.character() %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("#inner_content2 > div:nth-child(17) > div.disp_elm_value3 > table") %>% 
  html_table(),
error = function(e){NA} 
)
})
```

When I search for another patent (for example: "http://www.sumobrain.com/patents/us/Method-apparatus-quantitative-depth-differential/4982090.html") the child number changes to (18).

I am planning to analyse more than a thousand patents so I would need a code that work for both child numbers. Is there a CSS selector which allows me to select more children? I have tried the "div:nth-child(n)" and "div:nth-child(*)" but they do not work.

I am also open to using a different method. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks man that works very well.

Comment: Wecolme gl for the next, i going to look at web-scraping too ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **pseudo classes** :
It's a range between 17 and 18.

```
nth-child(17):nth-child(-n+18)
```